# Sequelize run migrations cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: sequelize.js

I created two models. After I want to create migrations for them.

Config model. The config has related 'hasMany' with domain. One config can has related with many domain.

```
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Config extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            Config.hasMany(models.domain, {
                foreignKey: 'configId',
                onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            });
        }
    }

    Config.init(
        {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            },
            country: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            tableName: 'configs',
            modelName: 'config',
            timestamps: false,
        },
    );
    return Config;
};
```

Config model. The domain has related 'belongsTo' with config. One domain can has related with one config.

```
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Domain extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            Domain.belongsTo(models.config, {
                foreignKey: 'configId',
            });
        }
    }

    Domain.init(
        {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            },
            domain: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            isActive: {
                type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
                allowNull: false,
                defaultValue: false,
            },
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            tableName: 'domains',
            modelName: 'domain',
            timestamps: false,
        },
    );
    return Domain;
};
```

After I created two migrations.

Config migration.

```
module.exports = {
    up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.createTable('configs', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            },
            country: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
        });
    },

    down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.dropTable('configs');
    },
};
```

Domain migration

```
module.exports = {
    up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.createTable('domains', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            },
            domain: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            isActive: {
                type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
                allowNull: false,
                defaultValue: false,
            },
            configId: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                onDelete: 'CASCADE',
                references: {
                    model: 'configs',
                    key: 'id',
                },
            },
        });
    },

    down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.dropTable('domains');
    },
};
```

Then I run my migrations and I got an error.

```
user@user-ps:~/Documents/projects/app-api$ npm run migration:run

> app-api@1.0.0 migration:run
> sequelize db:migrate


Sequelize CLI [Node: 15.3.0, CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 6.3.5]

Loaded configuration file "src/config/config.js".
== 20201130161539-affiliate: migrating =======

ERROR: Cannot add foreign key constraint

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/user/Documents/projects/app-api
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c sequelize db:migrate

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2020-12-01T16_51_54_422Z-debug.log
```

Where I made a mistake? I want to create migrations then I can run or revers then.

logs

```
Loaded configuration file "src/config/config.js".
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Executing (default): SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb';
Executing (default): SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `SequelizeMeta`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SequelizeMeta` (`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE , PRIMARY KEY (`name`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `SequelizeMeta`
Executing (default): SELECT `name` FROM `SequelizeMeta` AS `SequelizeMeta` ORDER BY `SequelizeMeta`.`name` ASC;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SequelizeMeta` (`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE , PRIMARY KEY (`name`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `SequelizeMeta`
Executing (default): SELECT `name` FROM `SequelizeMeta` AS `SequelizeMeta` ORDER BY `SequelizeMeta`.`name` ASC;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SequelizeMeta` (`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE , PRIMARY KEY (`name`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `SequelizeMeta`
Executing (default): SELECT `name` FROM `SequelizeMeta` AS `SequelizeMeta` ORDER BY `SequelizeMeta`.`name` ASC;
== 20201130161606-domain: migrating =======
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `domains` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `domain` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `isActive` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT false, `configId` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`configId`) REFERENCES `configs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Add `"logging":true` to other db connect options and try again

Comment: @Anatoly I added logs

Comment: Can you undo the first migration and apply moth migrations with logging?

Comment: My db is empty, I want to run migrations for create tables

Comment: I don't see a migration with `configs` table

Answer (score 0):

JS file order problem in the "migrations" path:
before generating the '*domains*' table, generate the '*configs*' table.